# Period of periodic functions

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

If I have a function $f(x) = \cos(x) + \sin(x)$ from graphing software, I know the period is $2 \pi$, but can that be shown algebraically? I understand why $\cos(x) = \cos(x + 2 \pi) $ and why $\sin(x) = \sin(x + 2\pi)$.

Moreover, what would the periods of $g(x) = \sin(x) + \tan(x)$ and $h(x) = \sin(x)\tan(x)$ be?

Comment: Hint: you can prove that $sin(x)+cos(x)=\sqrt 2  \sin (x+\frac \pi 4 )$

Comment: $g$ is $2\pi$ periodic since $g(x+2\pi)=g(x)$. The same applies for $h$ I think

Comment: @FareedAF All you've shown is the period *divides* $2\pi$.

Comment: Why don't you just compute $f(x + \alpha), g(x + \alpha), h(x + \alpha)$ and determine what you require $\alpha$ to be in order to return $f(x), g(x), h(x)$? For example, \begin{align} g(x + \alpha) &= \sin x \cos \alpha + \frac{\tan x}{1 - \tan x \tan \alpha} + \cos x \sin \alpha + \frac{\tan \alpha}{1 - \tan x \tan \alpha}\end{align} which implies $\cos \alpha = 1, \tan \alpha = 0, \sin \alpha = 0$ in order for $g(x + \alpha) = g(x)$. Also, note $\tan \alpha = 0 \implies \sin \alpha = 0$ and so all we need to do is solve $\cos \alpha = 1, \sin \alpha = 0$ for $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each function's period obviously divides $2\pi$. Let's take it from there.

As Michal Zapala has noted, $f=\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})$ has period $2\pi$.

Since $g=\tan x\,(1+\cos x)$ cannot return to its $x=0$ value of $0$ until $\tan x=0$ at multiples of $\pi$ or $\cos x =-1$ at odd multiples of $\pi$, $\pi$ divides the period, so it's $\pi$ or $2\pi$. But $x\mapsto x+\pi$ changes the sign of $g$, so the period will have to be $2\pi$ after all.

Similarly, since $h(x)=h(0)\implies \tan x = 0\implies  \pi | x$, $h$ has period $\pi$ or $2\pi$. In fact this time the period is $\pi$, since $h(x+\pi)=h(x)$.